# AutoMapper Mapping class using two sources

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I'm struggling to use automapper to map the DateTime properties in VistingHoursDTO to DateTimeOffset in VistingHours using the TimeZoneInfo in ethier Location or LocationDTO. The reason is the DateTime doesn't have the offset. I understand how to create the DateTimeOffset using DateTime and TimeZoneInfo. It just the mapping I'm not sure how to approach if you require a property from another parent mapping.

Update for Clarity:

I need to map VistingHoursDTO.Open (DateTime) -> VistingHours.Open (DateTimeOffset) using the Location.TimeZoneInfo and DateTime.

So;

```
VistingHours.Open = new DateTimeOffset(VistingHoursDTO.Open, Location.TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(VistingHoursDTO.Open))
```

Classes:

```
public class Location
{
    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZoneInfo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<VisitingHours> VisitingHours { get; set; }
}

public class LocationDTO
{
    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZoneInfo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<VisitingHours> VisitingHours { get; set; }
}

public class VisitingHours
{
    public DateTimeOffset Open { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Close { get; set; }
}

public class VisitingHoursDTO
{
    public DateTime Open { get; set; }
    public DateTime Close { get; set; }
}
```

AutoMapper Code example (no idea how to approach it):

```
CreateMap<Location, LocationDTO>()
    .ReverseMap();
            
CreateMap<VisitingHours, VisitingHoursDTO>()
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: You don't use VisitingHoursDTO in LocationDTO Typo? If you have those 2 mappings working you should just call AutoMappers Map function with your Location classes and Automapper should automatically pick up the mapping for VisitingHours. You need to have an explicit mapping for Datetime <-> DateTimeOffset. That needs external knowledge on how to do that. That makes ReverseMap alos not usable and you need to be explicit in both ways.

Comment: @Ralf yeah that's the aim. I need to map the DateTime properties in VistingHoursDTO to DateTimeOffset in VistingHours using the TimeZoneInfo in ethier Location or LocationDTO. As the DateTime doesnt have the offset.

Comment: Then create 2 mappings for VisitingHours and add a ForMember configuration to get from DatetimeOffset to Datetime and vice versa. See https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Projection.html?highlight=ForMember#projection

Comment: @Ralf sorry, I don't think I'm being clear, I'm aware how to map members. The issue is when mapping say from VistingHoursDTO.Open (DateTime) -> VistingHours.Open (DateTimeOffset), I also need the Locations TimeZone/TimeSpan to create the correct offset. So, new DateTimeOffset(VistingHoursDTO.Open, Location.TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(VistingHoursDTO.Open))

Comment: Then you need to map that also in the Location mapping config, without using the VisitingHours mapping and iterate over all VisitingHours in the ForMember delegate yourself. Alternatively make a VisitingHours mapping that maps into a Utc DateTime or a no offset DateTimeOffset. Then correct that in an AfterMap delegate of the  Location mapping with the help of the TimeZoneInfo into the correct value https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html?highlight=afterMap#before-and-after-map-action

Answer (score 0):

You can use the kind of the following one.

```
// From DTO to Model
CreateMap<VisitingHoursDTO, VisitingHours>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Open, option => option.MapFrom(src => GetOffsetFromDateTime(src.Open)))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Close, option => option.MapFrom(src => GetOffsetFromDateTime(src.Close)));

// From Model to DTO    
CreateMap<VisitingHours, VisitingHoursDTO>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Open, option => option.MapFrom(src => GetDateTimeFromOffset(src.Open)))
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Close, option => option.MapFrom(src => GetDateTimeFromOffset(src.Close)));
```

You have to write your transformation methods `GetOffsetFromDateTime` and `GetDateTimeFromOffset` depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry I don't think I was being very clear. I have updated my answer. Thanks